# Installing OpenSIS?

Tags: php

Im using OpenSIS version 5.2. I am trying to install it but after step 2 it just shows a blank box, I cannot proceed to step 3. I have installed this successfully in my other computer but in this one I cannot. They have the same apache, mysql, and PHP version. What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i hope im not too late. I had the same issue when installing openSis. The third page just loaded blank with no errors. Turns out I am on php 7.0 which dropped all support for php-mysql extension. So i now have to downgrade to php 5.6 or something. Hacked the source a bit and this error gave me a clue:-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

An old question but still this problem exists and the solution to that is:

1. Open the `php.ini` file in your PHP folder and search for `max_execution_time`.
2. When you find it, increase it to 3600 and save the file. Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds, i.e. `max_execution_time=3600`
3. Then restart Apache.
4. Try openSIS installation again.

Answer (score -2):

Basically turned error logging on and it turns out the blank page was caused by the session_state directory not have the correct permissions. That is for my install the PHP.ini file had put it in my documents and settings\local settings\temp\php or something like that. What you need to do is change the directory in the PHP.ini file to point to say c:\temp (make sure it exists!) and set the permission. To fault find grant everyone access to see if it works then work back from there.

The next issue was the install wouldn't connect to my SQL Server express database, so I was madly replacing dll's as per the WIKI!

Turns out though that the SQL Server express install by default doesn't allow named pipes or TCPIP connections hence cannot connect! You need to check this protocols are enabled

To enable TCP/IP:
From the Start menu, choose All Programs, point to Microsoft SQL Server 2005, point to Configuration Tools, and then click SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Optionally, you can open Computer Manager by right-clicking My Computer and choosing Manage. In Computer Management, expand Services and Applications, expand SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Expand SQL Server 2005 Network Configuration, and then click Protocols for InstanceName.

In the list of protocols, right-click the protocol you want to enable, and then click Enable.

The icon for the protocol will change to show that the protocol is enabled.

After this it was smooth. WIKI needs updating badly!

Comment: It is not clear if this answer relates to the question as asked. Certainly a lot of it doesn't.